# how to set value from page load to textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have use bellow code in page load function

```
 public string order_id = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.order_id = Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString();

    }
```

But in aspx page i did not get the order_id  variable value..
here i my textbox code onload page try to get value ..

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="order_id" runat="server" Text='<%=order_id %>'></asp:TextBox>
  </form>
```

please help me to get value Page_Load function to textbox..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString()))
            {
                order_id.Text = Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString();
            }
        }
```